# How to resolve validation error when querying with graphql? (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to query by passing in the `name` field but I get two different errors.

```
"Validation error of type MissingFieldArgument: 
  Missing field argument id @ 'getBlog'"
"Validation error of type UnknownArgument: 
  Unknown field argument name @ 'getBlog'"
```

I was able to successfully query it with the `id` field. Im new to graphql and im using this on my app that also uses aws amplify and aws appsync.

`schema.graphql`

```
type Blog @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @connection(keyName: "byBlog", fields: ["id"])
}
```

`queries.ts`

```
// this is an auto generated file. This will be overwritten

export const getBlog = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetBlog($name: String!) { //changed from ($id: ID!)
    getBlog(name: $name) { //changed from (id: $id)
      id
      name
      posts {
        items {
          id
          title
          blogID
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        nextToken
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

`app.tsx`

```
const getRecord = async () => {
        const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getBlog, {name: "testing"}))
        console.log(result) 
    }
```

I also tried pushing it to aws `amplify push` but it detected no changes. I didnt expect it to as i didnt change anything in the schema, only the queries. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your GraphQL *schema* you should see the definition for the `GetBlog` query. It likely looks like:

```
query {
  GetBlog(id: ID!): Blog
}
```

That particular query can only be queried by `id`. Assuming you have control of the server you should also be able to define a `GetBlogByName` query:

```
query {
  GetBlogByName(name: String): Blog
}
```

But then it will be up to you to ensure that `name` is unique or deal with potentially >1 response.

Comment: my result i get back is `"data": Object {"GetBlogByName": null,}`

Comment: Good news - you made it past type checking. Now you'll need to create the `GetBlogByName` *resolver* function as well on the server.